# How to get pipenv to work based on a symlink path rather than the real path

Tags: python, pipenv

Assuming my project name is `test`

symlink `test` --> `test_releases/test_v1`

```
cd test
pipenv shell
```

the above commands gives me a virutal env for the `test_v1` directory, 
but i would like to have virtualenv linked to `test`

bcoz wehn i update the projects and have symlink `test` --> `test_releases/test_v2`, its creating a new `test_v2` and i m having a lot of virtual envs piled up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such option available, i made a fork of pipenv and added my custom environemnt variable to get the required result

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an option to do this, at least in the latest version, by using the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable:

```
export VIRTUAL_ENV=/path/to/your/venv
pipenv shell
```

In your example above:

1. Create the physical directory `test` and run `pipenv install` from there to create the venv linked with the `test` directory. Let's assume (for example's sake) that it's created in `/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-nRgTMf73` (obviously your hash will most probably be different)
2. Remove the physical directory and make a symbolic link instead e.g. `test --> test_releases/test_v1`
3. `cd` into `test` now and run:

```
export VIRTUAL_ENV=/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/OfflineSystem-nRgTMf73
pipenv shell
```

This will use the original venv regardless of the symbolic link's physical target (i.e. the same for `test --> test_releases/test_v2` etc.)